# d3 is running in multiple times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am using normal `d3.js` in my react application. problem is this code is being executing multiple times if I put my code in `componentDidMount` it is running only single time. but it is giving my value undefined. if I add `componentDidUpdate` it is giving value properly but running `svg` componenet multiple times.  now don't know what to do?
below is my code

```
componentDidMount(){

    this.processData(this.props);
}
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){

    if(this.props.potentialBrandReturn== undefined)
      this.processData(this.props);


    return false;
  }

  processData(props){

    var data = [
      {
        label: 'Return',
        value: props.currentYearReturn,
        potential: props.potentialComReturn,
        color: '#aa3939'
      },
      {
        label: 'Brand',
        value: props.currentYearBrand,
        potential: props.potentialBrandReturn,
        color: '#2c4770'
      }
    ];

    var div = d3.select('body').append('div').attr('class', 'toolTip');

    var axisMargin = 20,
      margin = 40,
      valueMargin = 4,
      width = 550,
      height = 250,
      barHeight = 40,
      barPadding = 30,
      data,
      bar,
      svg,
      scale,
      scaleMark,
      xAxis,
      labelWidth = 0;

    var max = d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.potential;
    });

    svg = d3
      .select('#customChart2')
      .classed('svg-container1', true) //container class to make it responsive
      .append('svg')
      //responsive SVG needs these 2 attributes and no width and height attr
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
      .attr('viewBox', '0 0 600 200')
      //class to make it responsive
      .classed('svg-content-responsive', true);

    scale = d3.scale
      .linear()
      .domain([0, max])
      .range([0, 400 - margin * 2 - labelWidth]);

    bar = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g');

    bar.attr('class', 'bar').attr('cx', 0).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      return (
        'translate(' +
        margin +
        ',' +
        (i * (barHeight + barPadding) + barPadding) +
        ')'
      );
    });
    //appending lable
    bar
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
      .attr('dy', '.35em') //vertical align middle
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.label;
      })
      .each(function() {

        labelWidth = Math.ceil(Math.max(labelWidth, this.getBBox().width)) + 5;
      });

    //appending Potential rect

    bar
      .append('rect')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + labelWidth + ', 0)')
      .attr('height', barHeight)
      .style('fill', 'transparent')
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return scale(d.potential);
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        return tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
      })
      .on('mousemove', function(d) {
        return tooltip
          .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
          .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
          .text('Potential Value is $' + d.potential);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
      });

    //appending main bar for the chart
    bar
      .append('rect')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + labelWidth + ', 0)')
      .attr('height', barHeight)
      .style('fill', function(d) {
        return d.color;
      })
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return scale(d.value);
      })
      .on('mouseover', function() {
        return tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible');
      })
      .on('mousemove', function(d) {
        return tooltip
          .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 10 + 'px')
          .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
          .text('Actual Value is $' + d.value);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        return tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden');
      });

    // appending text for rect Potential
    bar
      .append('text')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + labelWidth + ', 0)')
      .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
      .attr('dy', '.35em') //vertical align middle
      .attr('x', 10)
      .attr('dx', function(d) {
        return scale(d.potential);
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return '$' + d.potential + ' Potential';
      });

    //appending value in side the rectangle
    bar
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'value')
      .attr('y', barHeight / 2)
      .attr('dx', function(d) {
        var temp = scale(d.value) + labelWidth;
        return temp - 10;
      }) //margin right
      //.attr("dx", valueMargin + labelWidth + margin) //margin right
      .attr('dy', '.35em') //vertical align middle
      .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
      .text(function(d) {
        return '$' + d.value;
      });

    // for tooltip message
    var tooltip = d3
      .select('body')
      .append('div')
      .attr('class', 'toolTip1')
      .style('position', 'absolute')
      .style('z-index', '10')
      .style('visibility', 'hidden');

    // appending the chart to html
    svg
      .insert('g', ':first-child')
      .attr('class', 'axisHorizontal')
      .attr(
        'transform',
        'translate(' +
          (margin + labelWidth) +
          ',' +
          (height - axisMargin - margin) +
          ')'
      );
    // .call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Just use the 'constructor' for initializing your data

Comment: Any time your state or props change componentDidUpdate is ran, which is causing the function to run multiple times

Comment: what value is undefined in componentDidMount function?

Comment: @TimCodes:`potentialComReturn` and `potentialBrandReturn` I tried that update by giving if condition oon potentialComReturn in `componentDidUpdate`   but t didn't work

Comment: what does your if statement look like ?

Comment: @TimCodes: have updated the code

Comment: need a flag to see if the data has been rendered yet

Comment: I didn't get you.. I have given condition undefined right?

Comment: you want to run it when the data is not undfiend and only once. so once the data is loaded set a flag to true saying the data is loaded, see below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isDataPopulated: false
      };
    }
    componentDidMount(){

    // delte call to  this.processData()
   }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        let potentialBrandReturn  = this.props.potentialBrandReturn === undefined;
        if(!potentialBrandReturn && !this.state.isDataPopulated)
          this.processData(this.props);
          this.setState({isDataPopulated : true})
        }else{
         return false;
        }


     }
```

Comment: checking for something other than undfined might be needed as well, like potentialBrandReturn > 0

Comment: hey It worked but partially previously I was able seeing `svg` 4 times now only 2 times. but still it's 2 times. any other addition??

Comment: not folowing you what do you mean by you saw svg 4 timjes ?

Comment: when I did inspect element I can see `svg` got rendered 4 times in my html. now it is got rendered 2 times

Comment: yes..my this component is a child component I don't know how it got renders 4 times

Comment: remove the process data call from componentDidMount

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153283/discussion-between-lowcool-and-timcodes).